# result of passing a symbol to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a method declaration with one argument :

```
def my_method(argum)
   if argum.empty?
      puts "argument is empty"
   else 
      puts "argument is not empty"
   end
end
```

when i call this method and i pass a **symbol** to it like : `my_method(:aleatoir_symbol)` it show me **argument is not empty** and when i pass a literal symbol to it like this `my_method(:"")` it show **argument is empty**

i also test with irb and this is the result :

```
:a_symbol.empty?
 => false
 :"".empty?
 => true
```

my question is why when i pass a symbol like **:any_symbol** it show **argument is not empty** ??

i'm searching and i find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246344/ror-tutorial-chapter-4-1-1-confused-why-title-helper-doesnt-fail?rq=1) but there are just one answer who given't me a clear comprehension of the reason. any clear answer will be helpful . thank's

** update **

---

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842658/why-does-a-variable-with-no-value-return-true-with-empty-when-used-in-a-view) is my original question, and i open this question because i don't have a good answer

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: I don't understand your question. In my opinion, this behaviour is fully expected.

Comment: my :symbol is not assigned with any value , i can't understand why is not empty ?!

Comment: What does "`symbol` not assigned with any value" mean?

Comment: Think of it this way: the name of the symbol *is* the value.

Comment: in rails for example i use a provide helper ex: provide(:title, "title of page") , and i have a method who take one argument like the method above : my_method(yield(:title),  and test if this argument is empty, when i don't use provide(:title, "title of page") it take argument as nonempty

Comment: It's not "assigning value to symbol". It's passing more than one argument to method.

Comment: passing more than one argument to method ? what this means ?

Comment: It means it's a method that takes more than one parameters, like this:
`def mymethod(a, b) puts [a,b]; end`. This is a method that takes two arguments and prints them on stdout. If you want to call it, you type for example `mymethod(:foo, :bar)`.

Comment: but my method take just one argument, i'm not a beginner lol perhaps my english is bad :( also i don't understand why people who are reading my question likes do -1 , i think this is for encouragement

Comment: @medBo I gave you downvote because your question is very difficult (or even impossible) to understand. I guess the others did it because of the same reason. You should be more clear. Look at the number of comments we produced to clarify the case and still no one knows exactly what you are asking for.
Still I don't understand why you expect `:symbol.empty?` to be `false`.

Comment: symbol is not an identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Symbol#empty`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Symbol.html#method-i-empty-3F) is basically defined as `self.to_s.empty?` (with `self` being the symbol).

So to answer your question **why** `:"".empty?` is `true`: It is because `:"".to_s` (the empty string) is empty.

To adress your comment: `:any_symbol.empty?` is `false`, because `:any_symbol.to_s.empty?` is `false`. It's the same thing. Maybe `empty?` is not the method you are looking for. Maybe I just didn't get what you are asking.

Comment: my question is why :any_symbol.empty? is nonempty ( don't ask about :"" )

Comment: @medBo Why it should be?
Why do you expect `:any_symbol.empty?` to return `false`?

Comment: i know that symbol is not a variable , and is used to design something not to have a value, but i'm confusing when i call a method who test if title passed to it is empty or not : full_title(yield(:title)) , here if i dont provide a title with provide(:title, "value"), it still nonempty

Comment: @medBo I read your comment twice and I still don't understand why you expect `:any_symbol.empty?` to return `false`. Please be more clear.